# How to serialize a generic JavaScript object to XML

Tags: javascript, xml, serialization

Does one of the mainstream JavaScript libraries (YUI, jQuery, Dojo) provide a way to serialize a JavaScript object to XML (as text)?

Answer (score 3):

There is **no** native API for native object to XML serializing; however, there are 3rd party libraries such as this one which will output XML:
http://code.google.com/p/x2js/

[See other threads on the subject.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772917/how-to-convert-or-serialize-javascript-data-object-or-model-to-xml-using-ext)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the best one, especially if you need to do it in Node.js https://github.com/wankdanker/node-object-to-xml