# Send JQuery DOM Object as XML to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

After searching Google for hours, I'm still stuck with this problem. Hope you guys can help me out.

I am building an application that lets user design their pages for a photo album. It first loads the standard format for each page using an XML. The XML is loaded through an AJAX call using JQuery as in:

```
$.get('http://www.domain.com/ajaxcall.php', function(responseXML) {
    $xmlDoc= $(responseXML);
)}
```

The XML file is now loaded as an object, and I can perform JQuery methods on it, which reduces the amount of code for me.

Editing from the user side is saved in the $xmlDoc. So when a user drags a photo over the page, the new cordinates are saved as an attribute of that photo. After all the user editing has been done, I want to export the new XML and save it to the server. This is where my problem starts. Since I've loaded the XML as a JQuery object (by using $(responseXML)), I can not export it as an XML file anymore. I've checked this by calling $.isXMLDoc($xmlDoc), which responds with false.

Since it was so easy to convert the XML to an object, I guess there must be a way to do the other way around. Any ideas on this?

XML from original file:

```
<pages>
 <page bgcolor="0099cc" titlecolor="f8f8f8" subtitlecolor="000000">
  <title>test</title>
  <subtitle></subtitle>
  <photo id="458267411204" name="" picture="http://www.domain.com/picture.jpg" height="540" width="720" x="25" y="0">
   <creator id="712241204" name=""/>
  </photo>
 </page>
</pages>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize a generic JavaScript object to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837577/how-to-serialize-a-generic-javascript-object-to-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I make the Ajax-call as the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.domain.com/ajaxcall.php"?,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/xml",
        processData: false,
        data: $xmlDoc.context,
        success: function(data) {
         alert('success');
        }
});
```

Then in ajaxcall.php I process the file and save it to the server:

```
$xmlcontent = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
$handle = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/userfiles/xml/book.xml', 'wb');
fwrite($handle,$xmlcontent);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure whether it works with XML but with HTML is dose:

```
$('<div>').append($xmlDoc).html()
```

I wrote a small fiddle to demonstrate my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/scheffield/3RhhF/

Have a try.

Comment: I wrote a fiddle... looky looky ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok It is not as straight forward to serialize the JavaScript object to XML.  The GSerializer library can be of use to you
[It can be found here](http://www.onegeek.com.au/projects/javascript-serialization)

or you should be able to get the HTML from the element to which it was appended by just using .html()

```
$(".div").html()
```

This can be saved into the database